# Return a different type according to an input parameter

Tags: scala

Let's see an example (it's a naive example but sufficient to illustrate the problem).

```
def produce(l: List[Int]) : Any =
  l match {
    case List(x) => x
    case List(x, y) => (x, y)
  }

val client1 : Int = produce(List(1)).asInstanceOf[Int]
```

Drawback : client need to cast !

```
def produce2[A](l: List[Int])(f: List[Int] => A) = {
  f(l)
}

val toOne = (l: List[Int]) => l.head
val toTwo = (l: List[Int]) => (l.head, l.tail.head)


val client2 : Int = produce2(List(1))(toOne)
```

Drawback : type safety, i.e. we can call toTwo with a singleton List.

Is there a better solution ?

Comment: Standard Scala `List` does not capture its length in its type, so you cannot prevent `toTwo` from being called with a list with too few elements. With an `HList` (e.g., from Shapeless), you could do this, since the types of each element (and hence intrinsically also the length) are statically known. If I actually knew how to write the specific code, I'd make this an answer, but my knowledge of Shapeless and `HList` is only "theoretical." Shapeless: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless

Answer (score 3):

If you only have two possible return values you could use Either:

```
def produce(l : List[Any]) : Either[Any, (Any, Any)] = l match {
    case List(x) => Left(x)
    case List(x, y) => Right((x, y))
}
```

If you don't want to create an `Either`, you could pass a function to transform each case:

```
def produce[A](l : List[Int])(sf: Int => A)(pf: (Int, Int) => A): A = l match {
    case List(x) => sf(x)
    case List(x, y) => pf(x, y)
}
```

Comment: Good idea to use `Either` but client still need some boilerplate to extract value from `Left` or `Right`, as in my first solution.

Comment: I love the idea to pass in the functions that process the result of the matching.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
  def produce(l: List[Int]) = {
     l match {
      case List(x) => (x, None)
      case List(x,y) => (x,y)
      case Nil => (None, None)
     }
   }
```

or even better, to avoid match errors on lists longer than 2 elements:

```
  def produce(l: List[Int]) =
     l match {
      case x :: Nil => (x, None)
      case x :: xs  => (x,xs.head)
      case Nil => (None, None)
     }
```

Comment: It will return (Any, Any), far from the strong typing that I want.